# ElasticSearch for Attribute(Key) value data set

Tags: e-commerce, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Elasticsearch with `Haystacksearch` and `Django` and want to search the follow structure:

```
{   
    {
        "title": "book1",
        "category" : ["Cat_1", "Cat_2"],
        "key_values" :
        [
            {
                "key_name" : "key_1",
                "value" : "sample_value_1"
            },
            {
                "key_name" : "key_2",
                "value" : "sample_value_12"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "title": "book2",
        "category" : ["Cat_3", "Cat_2"],
        "key_values" :
        [
            {
                "key_name" : "key_1",
                "value" : "sample_value_1"
            },
            {
                "key_name" : "key_3",
                "value" : "sample_value_6"
            },
            {
                "key_name" : "key_4",
                "value" : "sample_value_5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Right now I have set up an index model using Haystack with a "text" that put all the data together and runs a full text search! In my opinion this is not the a well established search 'cause I am not using my data set structure and hence this is some kind odd.
As an example if for an object I have a key-value

```
{
  "key_name": "key_1",
  "value": "sample_value_1"
}
```

and for another object I have

```
{
  "key_name": "key_2",
  "value": "sample_value_1"
}
```

and we it gets a query like "Key_1 sample_value_1" comes I get a thoroughly mixed result of objects who have these words in their fields rather than using their structures.

P.S. I am totally new to ElasticSearch and better to say new to the search technologies and challenges. I have searched the web and SO button didn't find anything satisfying. Please let me know if there is something wrong with my thoughts and expectations from these search engines and if there is SO duplicate question! And also if there is a better approach to design a database for this kind of search

Comment: You probably want to use nested types, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536820/how-to-avoid-cross-object-search-behavior-with-nested-types-in-elastic-search/17543151#17543151

Comment: I wish I'd seen the comment before answering!

Answer (score 1):

Read the [es docs on nested mappings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/) and do something like this:

```
"book_type" : {
    "properties" : {

        // title, cat mappings

        "key_values" : {
            "type" : "nested"
            "properties": {
                "key_name": {
                    "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then query [using a nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/)

```
"nested" : {
    "path" : "key_values",
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "term" : {"key_values.key_name" : "key_1"}
                },
                {
                    "match" : {"key_values.value" : "sample_value_1"}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is not exact answer to what I am searching but is halpful!:)

Comment: I think I want something that really does not exist as an Open Source project!
Here: user quary "a_book_name publisher sample_publisher"
What I have in the DB: I have an a_book_name object in my DB related with a Key, Value -> {"Publisher": "sample_publisher"}!
I want a search engine intelligently find keys in my quary and search similarities of the next words with values in the DB!
So, i don not want to put all DB object data in a text file and give it to the search engine! Think of a word quary "apple" that may exist in the title of the book or any other key, value!
Hope this help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm very confused. In your query "book_name publisher sample_publisher" how do you know if the word "publisher" is a key **or** another search term for the name field. If you can't give me a rule then how can you write a program? Have [a look at these docs on the lucene query parser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html). You might want to use something like that.

Comment: I mean that the SE tokenize the quary into words and search if it is in the keys or not! if yes, checks next words whether is similar to the the values or not! Thanks again for follow up!:)

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you, your method means you could never search for a book named "publisher". Or if you can then please describe how...

Comment: Yeah, I think you got what I mean! So, do you have any suggestions regarding to this?

Comment: Are you asking me to decide your specifications? I would probably do the easy thing and just search for all terms in all fields, that is if your user has only one search box. Otherwise I would use the lucene query parser linked above. Note, this is used in elasticsearch's `query_string` so you don't have to do the parsing yourself! Just write some example query under your box to help educate the user.

Comment: Please be kind enough some time to change your answer to the latest explanation so I could mark your answer as correct! THanks

Comment: If you post you're requirement in the question it would be much easier. I mean give me the **exact** search string and behaviour. I gave you two choices in the last comment, which do you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36011/discussion-between-mahdi-and-ramseykhalaf)