# Search for a single element in an array of dictionaries in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a JSON object of the following form in elasticsearch

```
             u'L3': [{u'ip': u'10.0.6.255',
                      u'port': 138,
                      u'protocol': u'UDP'},
                     {u'ip': u'10.0.6.104',
                      u'port': 137,
                      u'protocol': u'UDP'}],
```

How can I search for the document that contains a single array element with a given set of values of ip, port and protocol, and not match the documents where these values exist in separate array elements. 
So, if in this example, I were to search for L3.ip = 10.0.6.255 and L3.port = 137, it should *not* return the document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer -

[How to avoid cross object search behavior with nested types in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536820/how-to-avoid-cross-object-search-behavior-with-nested-types-in-elastic-search)

In short, use *nested* type.