# Searching a subset of nested objects within ElasticSearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have users indexed with documents such as these:

```
{
    "name": "Fred Jonsson",
    "age": 24,
    "emails": [
        {
            "active": false,
            "address": "fred.jonsson@burnabyhighschool.ca",
        },
        {
            "active": false,
            "address": "fjonsson4@kpu.ca",
        },
        {
            "active": true,
            "address": "fred@engineeringcorp.com",
        },
        {
            "active": false,
            "address": "fred@jonsson.me",
        },
   }
}
```

Does the *ElasticSearch DSL* allow me to construct a query where I could search for people by their e-mail address, but only if the address is active?  In more abstract terms, search documents by nested objects conditioned on other properties of those objects.

A search fulfilling this criterion would return this document for a search for `"fred@jonsson.me"` or `"engineeringcorp.com"`, but would not return this document when searching for `"fred.jonsson@burnabyhighschool.ca"`.

Comment: You are [looking for nested types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536820/how-to-avoid-cross-object-search-behavior-with-nested-types-in-elastic-search/17543151#17543151)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to initiate a nested query on your documents. In your mappings, you need to set "emails" as "type":"nested". This will create "hidden" documents of every object in your array that are associated with this parent document.

```
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "emails",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "active": {
                           "value": "true"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match": {
                        "address": "fred@jonsson.me"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to search for `email: fred.jonsson@burnabyhighschool.ca` which is `active`, you would do this:

```
{
  query: {
    nested: {
      path: 'emails',
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: {
                'emails.active': true
              }
            },
            {
              term: {
                'emails.address': "fred.jonsson@burnabyhighschool.ca"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortuntely, I don't have enough karma to upvote but I really appreciate your help.  This example is helping me start to understand the composition of queries with the ES DSL.