# "bool" filtering in Elasticsearch when searching in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with the understanding of the filter in Elasticsearch.I'm trying to build a filter to search the index, which has nested arrays.

```
     "bParams": {
                 "bParamList": [
                    {
                       "bParamId": 298,
                       "year": 2008,
                       "quarter": 4,
                       "value": 239698
                    },
                    {
                       "bParamId": 298,
                       "year": 2009,
                       "quarter": 4,
                       "value": 453
                    },
                    {
                       "bParamId": 298,
                       "year": 2007,
                       "quarter": 4,
                       "value": 190000
                    },
                    {
                       "bParamId": 304,
                       "year": 2009,
                       "quarter": 4,
                       "value": 7000
                    }
                 ]
             }
```

The request is:

```
 {
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "bParams.bParamList.year": [ 2007 ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "bParams.bParamList.value": {
                                "from": 1,
                                "to": 453
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "bParams.bParamList.bParamId": [ 304 ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
              }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

I expect that the query will not return any results, but the result is returned. I understand that there are elements with appropriate values​​. I need to take into account simultaneously all the request parameters.

Comment: Have you set up a `nested` mapping? You will need a nested query as well. Have a look at this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536820/how-to-avoid-cross-object-search-behavior-with-nested-types-in-elastic-search/17543151#17543151).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I treated this way. Is there another way to run properly without having to request the mapping? 
I have built an index, can I modify an existing mapping without reindexing?

Comment: As answered by @Alex, you need to reset the mapping and re-index all documents (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the `nested`-mapping, and you'll have to reindex to add it.

Without `nested`, what's indexed is essentially equivalent to this:

```
{
    "bParams": {
        "bParamList": {
            "bParamId": [298, 298, ...],
            "year": [2008, 2009, ...],
            "quarter": [4, 4, ...],
            "value", [239698, 453, ...],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Nested mapping changes the query result, if I want to search on a single field of the included mapping the nested fields?