# Elastic Search query for an AND condition on two properties of a nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the post_filter as below, Where I am trying to filter records where the school name is HILL SCHOOL **AND** containing a nested child object with name JOY **AND** section A.

school is present in the parent object, Which is holding children list of nested objects.

All of the above are AND conditions.

But the query doesn't seem to work. Any idea why ? And is there a way to combine the two nested queries?

```
GET /test_school/_search
{
"query": {
"match_all": {}
},
"post_filter": {
"bool": {
  "must_not": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "term": {
              "schoolname": {
                "value": "HILL SCHOOL"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "children",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "name": "JACK"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "children.section": {
                "value": "A"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

The schema is as below:

```
PUT /test_school
{
  "mappings": {
"_doc": {
  "properties": {
    "schoolname": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "children": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true
        },
        "section": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Sample data as below:

```
POST /test_school/_doc
{
"schoolname":"HILL SCHOOL",
"children":{
"name":"JOY",
"section":"A"
}
}
```

second record

```
POST /test_school/_doc
 {
"schoolname":"HILL SCHOOL",
"children":{
"name":"JACK",
"section":"B"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the mapping of your index `http://localhost:9200/<ur_index_name>/_mapping` and also try changing `term` to `match` in your query for `school` field.

Comment: If `children.section` is of type `text` then the problem might be that `A` is a stop word that's been removed during analysis. If you have ``children.section.keyword`, you might want to use that field instead

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal have updated with the schema.

Comment: @Val the field is marked as a keyword have added the schema.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to work" what do you mean?  An error?  No results?  The wrong results?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @batwad wrong results. The records are not getting filtered

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543151/183217 suggests special mapping is needed to work with nested objects.  You appear to be falling foul of the "cross object matching" problem.